# copy/paste range of cells x times based on condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, foreach

I want to fill each empty cells of a board with a precise range of data.

I 've got two worksheets;

-`worksheets("Board")`

- `worksheets("FinalBoard")`

In worksheet  `worksheets("Board")`  I've got the following board ;

| Category | Fruits-1 | Fruits-2 | Fruits-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Banana | Cherries | Orange |
| D | Apple | Mango | Strawberries |
| B | Pineapple | Watermelon | Grenade |

I want to pick each columns data only if the header starts with "Fruits" and paste them in one colum in worksheet   `worksheets("FinalBoard")` . I was able to do so with columns named Fruits, with the following code;

```
Sub P_Fruits()

 Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lRowInput As Long
    Dim lRowOutput As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim col As String
    
    '~~>  Sheets settings
    Set wsInput = Sheets("Board")
    Set wsOutput = Sheets("FinalBoard")

       
With wsInput
        '~~> Find last column in Row 2
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        '~~> loop through columns
        For i = 1 To lCol
            '~~>  research criterias
            If .Cells(1, i).Value2 Like "Fruit-*" Then
                '~~> Get columns name
                col = Split(.Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
                
                '~~> Get the last row in that column
                lRowInput = .range(col & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                
                '~~> Find the next row to write to
               If lRowOutput = 0 Then
                    lRowOutput = 2
               Else
                    lRowOutput = wsOutput.range("B" & wsOutput.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
                End If
                
                '~~> Copy-paste in the 2nd worksheet every data if the headers is found
                .range(col & "2:" & col & lRowInput).Copy _
                wsOutput.range("B" & lRowOutput)
                
      
            End If
      Next i
end with

end sub
```

**however I'd like to do so for the column "category"** and put the category's type in front of each fruits in column A and thus repeat the copied range category multiple time , as much as there were headers beginning with "Fruits" in  `worksheets("Board")` .  I tried to add an extra code to the previous one but it didnt work. Here is what I'd like as a result;

| Category-pasted | Fruits-pasted |
| --- | --- |
| A | Banana |
| D | Apple |
| B | Pineapple |
| A | Cherries |
| D | Melon |
| B | Watermelon |
| A | Orange |
| D | Strawberries |
| B | Grenade |

Here is what I had with the code I added instead...

| Category-pasted | Fruits-pasted |
| --- | --- |
|  | Banana |
|  | Apple |
|  | Pineapple |
|  | Cherries |
|  | Melon |
|  | Watermelon |
|  | Orange |
|  | Strawberries |
|  | Grenade |
| A |  |
| D |  |
| B |  |

My finale code;

```
Sub Fruits_add()

 Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lRowInput As Long
    Dim lRowOutput As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim col As String
    
    '~~>  Sheets settings
    Set wsInput = Sheets("Board")
    Set wsOutput = Sheets("FinalBoard")

       
With wsInput
        '~~> Find last column in Row 2
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        '~~> loop through columns
        For i = 1 To lCol
            '~~>  research criterias
            If .Cells(1, i).Value2 Like "Fruit-*" Then
                '~~> Get column name
                col = Split(.Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
                
                '~~> Get the last row in that column
                lRowInput = .range(col & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                
                '~~> Find the next row to write to
               If lRowOutput = 0 Then
                    lRowOutput = 2
               Else
                    lRowOutput = wsOutput.range("B" & wsOutput.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
                End If
                
                '~~> Copy-paste
                .range(col & "2:" & col & lRowInput).Copy _
                wsOutput.range("B" & lRowOutput)
                
      
            End If
      Next i
      
 'Code to repeat category type added     
With wsInput
        '~~> Find last column in Row 2
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        '~~> loop through columns
        For i = 1 To lCol
        
         '~~>  research criterias
            If .Cells(1, i).Value2 Like "Category*" Then
                '~~> Get column name
                col = Split(.Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
                
                '~~> Get the last row in that column
                lRowInput = .range(col & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                
                '~~> Find the next row to write to
               If lRowOutput = 0 Then
                    lRowOutput = 2
               Else
                    lRowOutput = wsOutput.range("A" & wsOutput.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
                End If
                
                '~~> copy-paste each category type in column A
                .range(col & "2:" & col & lRowInput).Copy _
                wsOutput.range("A" & lRowOutput)
                
                
                
         End If
      Next i
End With

      
      
End With
```

I feel like I'm close to the solution. I'd appreciate your help guys, thank you!

Comment: You don't need two loops - you already have the correct row with your first loop. Just add a second line of code after "                '~~> Copy-paste
                .range(col & "2:" & col & lRowInput).Copy _
                wsOutput.range("B" & lRowOutput)" and send it to column A from column 1

Comment: Your finale code has `If .Cells(1, i).Value2 Like "Fruit-*"` (no s) so I can't understand how you get that output with the headers `Fruits-1`

Comment: i Just edited and delete the "s" as the header begin with "fruit" don't contain any "s"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in my comments you don't need the second loop if you already found the correct row - get the category column early and reuse it later

You can add this variable declaration at the top first

```
Dim col As String
```

Then continue with your code for first loop (deleting second loop

```
With wsInput
        '~~> Find last column in Row 2
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        '~~> loop through columns
        For i = 1 To lCol
```

Add this to retrieve categories first

```
            If .Cells(1, i).Value2 Like "Category*" Then
            '~~> Get column name
               colCat = Split(.Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)                
            End If

            '~~>  research criterias
            If .Cells(1, i).Value2 Like "Fruit-*" Then
                '~~> Get column name
                col = Split(.Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
                
                '~~> Get the last row in that column
                lRowInput = .range(col & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                
                '~~> Find the next row to write to
               If lRowOutput = 0 Then
                    lRowOutput = 2
               Else
                    lRowOutput = wsOutput.range("B" & wsOutput.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
                End If
                
                '~~> Copy-paste
                .range(col & "2:" & col & lRowInput).Copy _
                wsOutput.range("B" & lRowOutput)
```

Then add this to paste the categories

```
            '~~> copy-paste each category type in column A
            .range(colCat & "2:" & colCat & lRowInput).Copy _
            wsOutput.range("A" & lRowOutput)
      
            End If
      Next i
End With
```

Comment: it took longer, but it eventually worked! Thank you so much !

Comment: However I 'v got a question, what if have to add extra conditions to take columns data based on their header ?( more than only category and fruits data column ?)

Comment: I think that's best asked in a new question with new example data and new code that you've attempted

Answer (score 2):

This code will produce the required results but uses a different approach.

The first thing it does is read the source data into an array, it then goes through that array and extracts the fruits/categories from every column with a header starting with 'Fruit.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Fruits_add()
Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim arrDataIn As Variant
Dim arrDataOut As Variant
Dim idxCol As Long
Dim idxRow As Long
Dim cnt As Long

    '~~>  Sheets settings
    Set wsInput = Sheets("Board")
    Set wsOutput = Sheets("FinalBoard")

    ' assumes data on 'Board' starts in A1
    With wsInput
        arrDataIn = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    End With
    
    ReDim arrDataOut(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arrDataIn, 1) * UBound(arrDataIn, 2))
    
    For idxCol = LBound(arrDataIn, 2) To UBound(arrDataIn, 2)
        If arrDataIn(1, idxCol) Like "Fruits*" Then
            For idxRow = LBound(arrDataIn, 1) + 1 To UBound(arrDataIn, 1)
                cnt = cnt + 1
                arrDataOut(1, cnt) = arrDataIn(idxRow, 1)
                arrDataOut(2, cnt) = arrDataIn(idxRow, idxCol)
            Next idxRow
        End If
    Next idxCol
    
    If cnt > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrDataOut(1 To 2, 1 To cnt)
    End If
    
    With wsOutput
        .Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Category-pasted", "Fruit-pasted")
        .Range("A2").Resize(cnt, 2) = Application.Transpose(arrDataOut)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Definitely will work faster using arrays. Good job.